# Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined at makeApiCall?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

[image: please click here to see the error message, while i am integrating the google calendar using javascript i'm getting this error]

```
 function makeApiCall(){   
   
 gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () { 
        
                 var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert
                 console.log(request);
                 ({
                    'calendarId': '', 
                    "resource": resource    
                });  
     
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have forgotten to post a section of your code you have probably forgotten to register the library, as well as authorizing the user.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
```

## full example using Google sign-in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello cal v3 </title>
    <!-- Create a client id on Google developer console. Web credentials https://youtu.be/pBVAyU4pZOU  -->
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
          content="YourClientId">
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello cal v3 </h1>

<!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `getFileAsync()` on success. -->
<p class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="makeacall"></p>

<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>

    // Query the API and print the results to the page.
    async function makeacall() {

        try {
            await gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3');
            const response = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                calendarId: 'XXX', 
                resource: resource
            });
         displayResults(response)
            
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error getting files', e)
        }
    }

 function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
}


</script>

<!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library.   -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
```

## Redirect uri mismatch JavaScript origin error

Make sure that you have configured your web client properly on Google developer console and added the proper javascript origin.  [Simple solution for redirect_uri_mismatch error with JavaScript](https://youtu.be/V0-4LnHwFho)

Comment: The JavaScript origin in the request, http://localhost:9001, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number} to update the authorized JavaScript origins.

Comment: after clicking signin button this is how it's showing

Comment: You need to set up the Javascript origin properly in Google developer console for your web client.  https://youtu.be/V0-4LnHwFho

Comment: The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. If you think you should have access, contact the developer (venkatasubbareddy.singamala@gmail.com).

Comment: after giving gmail and password it's showing like. i have watch the video you shred it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to init gapi on page load

```
gapi.auth2.init({
   client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
});
```

Comment: Have you add`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plus.js?onload=init"></script>`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
    at makeApiCall (calendar.html:83)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick